# Why doesn't a method containing an async lambda need to be Async itself?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, c#-5.0

For example, whenever I await something the compiler notifies me the containing method must be Async. Why is the async lamba not seen this way? If the ForEach is hiding it then is there some danger regarding not returning a Task object and the ForEach being implicitly async void?

```
public void SaveSome()
{
    Array.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0,3).ToArray(), async x =>  await SaveRep());
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An async lambda is just a simple way of creating a delegate which is asynchronous. There's nothing to say that the method which contains it has to be doing *anything* asynchronous itself - and any `await` expressions within the lambda expression won't make the containing method wait (unless it's awaiting a task which happens to rely on the delegate, of course).

Basically the lambda expression is *expressing* some asynchronous code - it's not *executing* the asynchronous code itself... so the containing method isn't necessarily executing asynchronously.

Yes, the example you've given is a misuse of async lambdas - but making the method async wouldn't improve matters at all, and it would simply be misleading.

EDIT: As an alternative way of thinking about it, consider this refactoring of your original code:

```
public void SaveSome()
{
    Action<int> action = SaveRepAsync;
    Array.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0,3).ToArray(), action);
}

private static async void SaveRepAsync(int x)
{
    await SaveRep();
}
```

The `SaveSome` method has *nothing* asynchronous about it - only the `SaveRepAsync` method does... so that's what requires the `async` modifier. This really is just a tiny refactoring of your code (the sort of refactoring the compiler would do, effectively). If you wanted every method containing an async lambda to have the async modifier, that's like saying that in the above code, `SaveSome` should have the modifier too... which would make no sense, IMO.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain a little more about why the above is a bad idea in production code. My current mental model of async requires that: 1)All async calls are called from within an async method with return type Task or Task<> 2)Do this all the way up the call stack as if an exception is thrown Task will hold the exception 3)Only event handlers should be async void. So this is language legal but bad, why? Are I guidelines right?

Comment: @Jaycee: Well you're calling `Array.ForEach` which would normally do things in series - but your async lambda *just* awaits something else. You're effectively just doing a fire-and-forget operation, but without any indication of when everything's finished. If you *really* want a completely fire-and-forget approach, I'd personally choose a different way of expressing it. As far as `Array.ForEach` is concerned, it's just being given an `Action<int>`.

Comment: @Jaycee: A safer solution would be `await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(x => SaveRep()))`, which projects each element into a `Task` and then awaits them all. That way you avoid `async void`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Well that's changing the meaning, of course - that won't complete until all the saves have completed. Currently we don't really know what the OP is trying to achieve, which makes it rather difficult to help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks both, this was just some unit test code I was curious about. I originally had a for loop and then CodeRush gave me an option to make it a 1 liner. I assume my guidelines are acceptable then.

Comment: @Jaycee: Yes, they seem reasonable. I would definitely avoid refactoring to `Array.ForEach` like this - a simple `for` loop is *much* easier to understand, IMO.

Comment: @Jaycee: I've edited my answer to give a refactoring of your existing code to a version where it's more obvious why the `SaveSome` method doesn't need to be async.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for this! I agree about the for loop BTW. I would assess that particular refactoring for readability on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 4):

You can only `await` an `async` method in an `async` method, but you *can still call them* in a non-async method, like you're doing above - in this case, it's more a "fire and forget"